# RSS feed for favorite question activity

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, rss

I have a RSS feed link called **user feed** at

```
[site-name]/users/[userid]/[username]
```

Are there any similar RSS feed links to track the activities on my favorite questions?

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in functionality for this, but someone wrote a tool: [RSS feed for favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64987/167646)

Here's a feed of your favourite questions: http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/1391924/favorites?body=true

Comment: oops second link stopped working getting `There was an error processing this page.The API response did not contain an array`.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Can you comment on the answer I linked to? It's posted by the author of the tool.

Comment: The tool isn't yet working with the new version of STackOverflow's API, but it's on github: https://github.com/nathan-osman/stack2rss