# Get Notification when a question you upvoted is answered

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Sometimes when I browse new questions I find a well written, interesting question which I can't answer. If this happens, I'll normally just upvote the question so that it will be more visible to others who might be able to answer it.

However, at the moment I don't get a notification when this question is answered. I upvoted the question because I'm interested in it, so I am likely also interested in the answer. But without a notification I either forget about the question or it is hard for me to find it again.

So I think when you upvote a question from someone else and the original asker accepts an answer, the upvoters should be notified that the question has been answered.

Comment: Maybe you should favorite such questions. You can then sort in your profile the favorite questions on activity. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278200/favorite-a-question-but-no-up-vote

Comment: related, this might be even a dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253981/rss-feed-for-favorite-question-activity

Comment: Do know that a lot of us vote on stuff. I voted on nearly 10,000 posts. I imagine my inbox would be filled with messages.

Comment: maybe a dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252512/whats-the-use-of-favourite-this-question

Comment: Also see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302607/is-it-possible-to-get-notifications-of-question-activity-without-adding-a-commen (not a duplicate, though, since yours is a feature-request).

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes users upvote good questions even if they already know the answer, or when they don't care about the answer. Why? Because we encourage good, descriptive, and well-written questions, because they might be relevant to other users.

I don't want noisy notifications to fill my inbox. If I want to "follow" a post, I do so by marking it as a [favorite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252512/whats-the-use-of-favourite-this-question).

Comment: In other words, don't merge the way we *rate* content with content we want to *subscribe* to.

Comment: It's exactly this: Up-voting a post doesn't mean I want to get notified of new  answers. Imagine being active in 3 SE sites, and getting a notification for all the up-voted questions. Even limiting this to questions without an answer that get answers later, it would still a nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to find out when a question is answered then favorite it.  You can see which of your favorites questions have been answered since you last viewed them.